# Xcode Server "cannot connect to server" after restart

Tags: ios, xcode9, xcode-server

I just installed and setup Xcode 9 on my laptop, i've also installed Xcode 9 on a Mac Mini and enabled Xcode server on it, and created a second user "xcodeserver".

I went to the Xcode server website, found my integration, installed the profile, manually trusted the xcode server CA, and was able to install the app on my device. I restarted the Mac Mini and now clicking install on any device returns "Cannot connect to ...".

I've deleted the profiles and the cert and re-installed, restarted the server again (all several times) with no luck.

Using Xcode 9 on the laptop I was able to view the integration, and download and install the .ipa on a device. So there is clearly no issue with the signing. But I need to enable the website for remote users.

I also get a time out error trying to download the archive through Xcode on the laptop, but not the .ipa

Has anyone faced similar issues? Most of the workarounds online are instructing how to trust the CA, which i've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here for anyone else facing the same issue. Can't explain why, but logging into the mac mini and turning the server on / off didn't help but logging in and:

- Turn off the server
- Switch to the admin user
- Turn server on
- Turn off server
- Switch back to normal user
- Turn server on

Fixed the issue. I'm guessing something somewhere got corrupted and thats the only way to refresh the whole thing.